# jQuery - Delay ajax so CSS transition has time to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an Ajax call in jQuery like this...

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'filter',
        },
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            $('#results').css("opacity" , "0.5");
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#results').css("opacity" , "1");
            $('#results').html(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            /* Display Ajax Error Message */
            $("#results").html('<p>There has been an error</p>');
        }
    });
```

This is working well, it fades out the results whilst it is loading and then fades them in when it has found them.

The problem is that sometimes, if there are only a few results, they are returned before the opacity transitions has finished, this is currently set to 0.5s using CSS.

Is there a way to delay the results, or ensure that at least 0.5s seconds has passed so that the opacity transition has time to run?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` for this inside your `success` function.

Comment: use `setTimeout(function(){  $('#results').html(data);}, 3000);` where you are loading html inside `success`

Answer (score 0):

You better use css animation delay. It is lighter, than setTimeout().

Check the link to see how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$.ajax({
    (...)
    success: function(data) {
        $('#results').css("opacity" , "1");
        $('#results').html(data);
    },
    (...)
});
```

with:

```
$.ajax({
    (...)
    success: function(data) {
      var delayTime = 500 // 0.5s in milliseconds

      $('#results').css('opacity' , '1');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#results').html(data);
      }, delayTime);
    }
    (...)
});
```

*As a side note:* Try to be consistent and use the same " " or ' ' set of quotes throughout your code it helps avoiding bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better solution you can try.
You can add one more literals to $.ajax object i.e.

```
$.ajax({
    (...)
    success: function(data) {
      $('#results').html(data);
    },
    error: function(){},
    complete: function(){
      $('#results').css('opacity' , '1');
    }
});
```

The **complete function** runs, when your all methods performed its work. **you just store the data returned from server to results DOM inside success method** and **add css to result DOM inside complete method**. Complete method will run with respect to all methods, including success method and will show your result DOM at final stage of execution. 
Hope you got the solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the stop(true - stops the animation wherever it is) method with jquery animate( will continue to proceed from the last step it remained to where you want it to be) :

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_stop.asp

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajax_url,
    data: {
        action: 'filter',
    },
    beforeSend: function ()
    {
        $('#results').stop(true).animate({
        "opacity" : "0.5"
        }, 500 , function(){ // 500 is duration in ms
          console.log('beforeSend animation stopped');
     });
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#results').stop(true).animate({
        "opacity" : "1"
        }, 1000 , function(){ // 1000 is 1s
          console.log('success animation stopped');
           $('#results').html(data);
     });

    },
    error: function()
    {
        /* Display Ajax Error Message */
        $("#results").html('<p>There has been an error</p>');
    }
});
```